# Identify mobile-network state on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, network-programming

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to get the mobile network state on an iPhone. i.e: Identify if a an iPhone can make a phone call or send a SMS.

I have gone over all of reachability documentation and all I could find is reference to identifying the state of the internet connection but not the mobile network state.

Any leads may help.

Comment: u need  mobile company carrier name of iphone

Answer (score 1):

you have to use CoreTelephone Framework :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html

you should use methods like `subscriberCellularProvider` to get info about the cellular network provider.